# Underline file names that do not match type name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, code-inspection

I have just reinstalled Visual Studio 2019 with ReSharper and I see that my environment is missing one code inspection rule: **file names that do not match type name**.

I don't remember if this code inspection rule was built-in VS or it was a ReSharper rule or even a VS extension. ReSharper allows me to `Rename file to match type name` when right-click a class with non-matching file name but in my editor the class is not underlined. In my previous VS installation when this code inspection issue was triggered the class was undelined.

Anyone could tell me how can I enable this code inspection rule, whether in ReSharper, VS or a  VS extension?

Comment: Were you using [CodeRush](https://docs.devexpress.com/CodeRush/10193/concepts/code-analysis/code-issues/type-name-does-not-correspond-to-file-name) before?

Comment: @KannanSuresh Thanks for your reply. No, I haven't been using this.

Answer (score 0):

Neither Visual Studio nor ReSharper will highlight this issue but both will offer a quick fix to correct it.

Adding the StyleCop.Analyzers NuGet package will add the [SA1649](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1649.md) warnings (and squiggly underlines).

Using Visual Studio 2019 (16.8.4) with ReSharper 2020.3.2, C# Console application using .net 5 and the StyleCop.Analyzers v1.2.0-beta.321 NuGet package give me this:

[image]

If you look under your project in the Solution Explorer, under `Dependencies`->`Analyzers`->`StyleCop.Analyzers` you will see a long list of all the StyleCop rules, scroll down to `SA1649` and right click on it and select `Set Severity`->`Warning`.

There is also a StyleCop extension for ReSharper but I had some issues with it a while ago with some of the newer C# language features.

Comment: I had StyleCop installed once, but I think it was a long time ago. Based on your sugestion I have just installed both the StyleCop extension for ReSharper and the VS one but unfortunately they don't highlight this rule by default. For sure I have not tweaked the StyleCop options in the past.

Comment: I have added some more detail. Are you using the same versions as me? This should work also without ReSharper.

Comment: Try the NuGet package rather than the extension. You may also have an old StyleCop settings file (`Settings.StyleCop`) that is disabling some rules.

Comment: I have never used the StyleCop.Analysers package and I would like to avoid using it. I don't like the idea to install this nuget package for every project

Comment: The NuGet package has the advantage that you only need to apply it to the projects you want whereas the StyleCop extension applies to every thing you use, open some legacy code and you'll be neck deep in squigglies. This method will also work for enforcing coding standards to all users rather than those who have ReSharper/StyleCop extension.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use ReSharper. I use the default .NET analyzer and Roslynator. Both of them does not show this inspection.

This seems to be a code inspection from ReSharper. You might have turned it off.

See the URLs below.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Move_Types_into_Matching_Files.html

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/StyleCop_Styles.html#applying-settings-from-settings-stylecop-files

Comment: That's right, there is a code inspection rule but I can't get it to enable highlighting

Comment: Check this [help file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/StyleCop_Styles.html#applying-settings-from-settings-stylecop-files) too. It seems like a configuration. Since I don't have Resharper, I cannot try from my side.